# While loop within a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have one table which contains events and dates, and another which contains the guestlist for each of these nights. I can print the nights like so:

```
$day = date("l");
$date = getFullDateString($day);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nights WHERE day = '$day' AND promoter = 'blah'") or die(mysql_error);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h2>";
    echo $row[name];
    echo " (";
    echo getFullDateString($row[day]);
    echo ")</h2>";
}
```

The problem is that for each of these events I want the guestlist to be printed below it. I've tried putting another `while` loop inside, but even the test echo doesn't work.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT guest FROM guestlists WHERE night = '$row[name]' AND date = 'getFullDateString($row[day])'") or die(mysql_error ());

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        echo $row2[0];
        echo "test";
        echo "<br />";
}
```

Essentially I want the following:

> **Event 1**
>
> Name 1
>
> Name 2
>
> Name 3
>
> **Event 2**
>
> Name 1
>
> Name 2
>
> Name 3

Comment: are you having event id in guestlist table?

Comment: does the table have entries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a method inside the query string which won't be run.

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT guest FROM guestlists WHERE night = '".$row['name']."' AND `date` = '".getFullDateString($row['day'])."'"
```

Also, `date` is a reserved word in MySQL and should be encapsulated within backticks or changed to something else.

Additionally, the [`mysql_`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) functions are being deprecated and it is recommended to replace them with [PDO or MySQLi](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Complex (curly) syntax for string parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) to learn the proper way to embed your variables in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nights WHERE day = '".$day."' AND promoter = 'blah'") or die(mysql_error);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h2>".$row[cname]."</h2>";

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT guest FROM guestlists WHERE night = '$row[name]' AND date = '".getFullDateString($row[day])."'") or die(mysql_error);

   while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))  
    {
        echo $row2[cname];  
    }

}
```